# When and how many times can a clojure file be evaluated with leiningen?

Tags: clojure, compilation, leiningen

I found while adding warnings to code that writes macros that the body of a file was being executed twice during compilation.  Is there a reason for this?  Is this specific to leiningen?  I can not reproduce this with `(compile ...)`.

Simplified version:

```
(ns foo.core
    (:require foo.bar))

;; empty
```

---

```
(ns foo.bar)

(println "hello")
```

> $ lein compile :all
>
> Compiling foo.core
>
> `hello`
>
> Compiling foo.bar
>
> `hello`

Further testing shows that the namespace is reloaded on top of itself during compile:

```
(ns foo.bar)

(declare wasd)
(println wasd)
(def wasd 2)
```

> $ lein clean
>
> $ lein compile :all
>
> Compiling foo.core
>
> `#<Unbound Unbound: #'foo.bar/wasd>`
>
> Compiling foo.bar
>
> `2`

In a more complicated case I have this happening during compile, and then once every time when run or started a repl from lein.  I am not sure why.  This is all with clojure 1.6 and leiningen 2.5.0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Leiningen knows nothing about the structure of your project in terms of how namespaces relate to each-other. Consequently, when compiling a project, `lein` simply boots a JVM and forces each namespace to be loaded one at a time. This means that, as you noticed, namespaces will be reloaded causing the double evaluation behaviour you are noticing.

In comparison, [`(clojure.core/compile)`](http://conj.io/1.6.0/clojure.core/compile) simply loads the targeted resource with [`clojure.core/*compile-files*`](http://conj.io/1.6.0/clojure.core/*compile-files*) bound. This will cause the targeted resource and all the resources it requires to be loaded and compiled to class-files. However, it will *not* traverse your entire project structure compiling *all* resources as Leiningen's compile operation does.

Comment: I don't understand.  Why does "forc[ing] each namespace to be loaded one at a time" imply that "namespaces will be reloaded"?

Comment: If namespace A requires B, in order to load A, B must first be loaded. Thus if you first load A and then B, loading A will load B and then you will cause B to be reloaded.

Comment: This seems right.  Checking the source of the [compile task](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/src/leiningen/compile.clj), it just calls `clojure.core/compile` on each file in turn.  I assumed there were more "brains" behind it than that.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you're seeing `println` output during compile time is because `println` is called during namespace evaluation. You  should have a `-main` fn or some other entry point for your program that calls on `println`.

```
(defn -main [& _]
  (println "Won't see on compile.")
  (println "lein run -- is printing from -main"))
```

I think your project is throwing an Unbound Exception because you're trying to  reference the `wasd` variable with `println` before a value is assigned to it. The variable was declared, but nothing was assigned to it before the `println` fn tried to get the value.

Comment: The point of that example was that the second time the variable is already bound. It was used to prove that the namespace was loaded twice. The initial unbound was expected.